# Restangular ignore setRequestInterceptor once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

In the setup of my app, I use Restangular.setRequestInterceptor() to call a function that shows a loading screen anytime I make a request with Restangular.

However, there is one spot in my app where I don't want it to call that function. How can I tell Restangular to ignore the setRequestInterceptor function for this one call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that runs into this problem, it turns out Restangular lets you create a separate Restangular service with different configuration options than the global one. This example from the [Restangular GitHub](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-to-create-a-restangular-service-with-a-different-configuration-from-the-global-one) shows how:

```
// Global configuration
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://www.google.com');
  RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('.json');
});

// Restangular service that uses Bing
app.factory('BingRestangular', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://www.bing.com');
  });
});

// Let's use them from a controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', function(Restangular, BingRestangular) {

  // GET to http://www.google.com/users.json
  // Uses global configuration
  Restangular.all('users').getList()

  // GET to http://www.bing.com/users.json
  // Uses Bing configuration which is based on Global one, therefore .json is added.
  BingRestangular.all('users').getList()
});
```